# Running Tensorflow on CMD Line Error

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I am trying to run MNIST prediction using tensorflow.

Files:

```
 https://github.com/niektemme/tensorflow-mnist-predict/
```

CMD Line Code:

```
 python predict_1.py ‘number1.png’
```

I can execute the program in PyCharm without an error, but when I try executing the script through the command line, I get an error.

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "predict_1.py", line 29, in <module>
     import tensorflow as tf
 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'
```

I checked pip3 list to confirm installed:
     tensorflow (1.0.1)

Update1:

I ran this test in both environments:
     import os
     print(os.**file**)

PyCharm:

```
C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\python.exe 
C:/Users//AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35/Scripts/tensorflow-mnist-predict-master/tensorflow-mnist-predict-master/test.py
C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\os.py
```

CMD Line:

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\os.py
```

Update2:

I removed Anaconda3 from the environment variables, and

CMD Line now reads:

```
C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\os.py
```

This is the error I get trying to run tensorflow through the CMD line:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module(mname)
  File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 666, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 577, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 906, in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 54, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 21, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow')
  File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "predict_1.py", line 29, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 60, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module(mname)
  File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 666, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 577, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 906, in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 54, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 21, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow')
  File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow'


Error importing tensorflow.  Unless you are using bazel,
you should not try to import tensorflow from its source directory;
please exit the tensorflow source tree, and relaunch your python interpreter from there.
```

Comment: can you do `python -v` and `which python` (or `where python` on windows?). Probably running on another python install you're not aware of.

Comment: Python 3.5 Windows

Comment: `where python` should bring you to python installation dir. Check that "tensorflow" is located in "lib\site-packages"

Comment: tensorflow is located in "lib\site-packages"

Comment: okay, then before importing it, just do `import os; print(os.__file__)` for starters and report the result.

Comment: C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\python.exe 

C:/Users//AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35/Scripts/tensorflow-mnist-predict-master/tensorflow-mnist-predict-master/test.py

C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\os.py

Comment: so `C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib` should contain `site-packages\tensorflow`. If it doesn't then you have 2 separate versions of python, one without tensorflow: the one you're running.

Comment: C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Lib\site-packages is where tensorflow is located

Comment: When I run 'import os; print(os.__file__)' on the CMD line, it doesnt show the Python35 folder, only C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\os.py

Answer (score 0):

Judging from your edits, you have two separate python installations, one in `Users\AppData` and one in `ProgramData\Anaconda3`. Your PyCharm uses the first one, but when you just run `python` command from CLI you get the second one. There are two ways to resolve this, you can adjust your PATH variable to point to the first installation, so `python` from CLI is the same as your PyCharm or you can install TensorFlow on the second install (this might lead to further confusion if there are other libraries your code depends on). Here is a link with directions on editing your PATH variable (https://www.howtogeek.com/118594/how-to-edit-your-system-path-for-easy-command-line-access/). You want to make sure that `C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35` is in there and `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3` is not.